# Decimal to binary C while dividing by 2

Tags: c, unix, math

I have to write 2 programs that convert dec to bin. I've finish the 1st one however when I try to run this one it prints out an array of random number not sure why, here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumber();
int dectoBin(int, int binarray[], int);
void printBin(int binary[], int dec);

int main()
{
    int M = 8;
    int binarray[M];
    int dec = getNumber();
    printf("The decimal number you entered was: %d", dec);
    decToBin(dec, binarray, M);
    printBin(binarray, dec);
    return 0;
}

int getNumber()
{
    int dec;
    printf("Enter any a number between 0 and 255: ");
    scanf("%d",&dec);
    return dec;
}

int decToBin(int dec, int binarray[], int M)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=8; i>=0;i--)
    {
        while(dec != 0)
        {
            binarray[i]= dec % 2;
            dec = dec / 2; binarray[i] = dec; 
        }
    }
    return *binarray;
}

void printBin(int binary[], int dec)
{
    int i;
    if(dec > 255)    
    {
        printf("please use another number");
        main();
    }
    else
    {
        for(i =8; i >= 0;i--)
        {
            printf("%d", binary[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `decToBin` looks very broken to me - there shouldn't be two loops. Also your `for` loops are iterating over the wrong range (8..0 - should be 7..0). Otherwise the code looks mostly OK.

Comment: Check return value of `scanf`. With your current code, if there is parse error, uninitialized garbage value is returned from `getNumber()`.

Comment: Please try to avoid `if(){main()}` - that is a terrible code structure.

Comment: `for(i=8; i>=0;i--)` is 9 loops.  Suggest `for(i=M; i-- > 0 ; )`

Comment: `while(dec != 0) { binarray[i]= dec % 2; ...` unexpected results when `dec < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `binarray[i]` twice - once correctly (after the modulus statement) and once incorrectly (after dividing dec). So if your decimal number is `65`, your second-to-last number would be `32`.

You can also make `binarray` an array of bits rather than numbers. This would have given you a error on compilation and would have perhaps clued you into the logical error.

**EDIT:** There are a lot of control flow issues with this program. You should check to see if `dec > 255` BEFORE calling `decToBin` otherwise the program will run incorrectly. `decToBinary` shouldn't return an `int` - it should return an array of `int`s (or bits as I suggested) and that is what you should send to `printBin`. Right now you're returning the pointer to `binArray` (do you know what pointers are?) `decToBin` should also return `void` since it does not perform any calculations.

**EDIT 2:** As someone else pointed out your array indexes are incorrect, I don't know how you haven't gotten an array out of bounds error. Also, while printing you're going the wrong way: You need to use a `for` loop that starts at `0` and ends at `7`.

Comment: One final thing: You're showing good encapsulation here by having a lot of methods. But in C you're going to get stuck on a lot of different problems with returning and passing for a simple program.

My suggestion would be to print the binArray directly after "constructing" it. Remember to keep in mind the method that you'd use on paper for generating a binary number from a decimal (dividing by two, and then setting the rightmost bit to the remainder, before performing the operation once more).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions.

1. You have `dectoBin` in the declaration but `decToBin` in the function call and function definition. Make sure they are all `dectoBin` or they are all `decToBin`.
2. `M` is not used in `decToBin`. Feel free to remove it.
3. I would change `getNumber()` such that it checks for the range and makes sure that you get a number between 0 to 255 from its return statement. That would eliminate the need to do that check in `printBin`.
4. Implementation of `decToBin` is quite a bit simpler than what you were thinking. The for-loop can be simplified to:

   ```
    for(i=7; i>=0;i--, dec /= 2)
    {
       binarray[i]= dec % 2;
    }
   ```
5. And finally, implementation of `printBin` can be a little bit different to make the output more readable. Instead of printing one number at a time, they can all be printed in one line.

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumber();
int decToBin(int, int binarray[]);
void printBin(int binary[], int dec);

int main()
{
   int M = 8;
   int binarray[M];
   int dec = getNumber();
   printf("The decimal number you entered was: %d\n", dec);
   decToBin(dec, binarray);
   printBin(binarray, dec);
   return 0;
}

int getNumber()
{
   int dec;
   printf("Enter a number between 0 and 255: ");
   scanf("%d",&dec);
   if( dec < 0 || dec > 255)
   {
      printf("Please use another number\n");
      return getNumber();
   }
   return dec;
}

int decToBin(int dec, int binarray[])
{
   int i;
   for(i=7; i>=0;i--, dec /= 2)
   {
      binarray[i]= dec % 2;
   }
   return *binarray;
}

void printBin(int binary[], int dec)
{
   int i;
   printf("The decimal number in binary: ");
   for(i=0; i!=8; ++i)
   {
      printf("%d", binary[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

A sample execution and output:

```
~>>./test-07
Enter a number between 0 and 255: 149
The decimal number you entered was: 149
The decimal number in binary: 10010101
```

Comment: Thank you I did something similar to this, but I see how you change the decToBin function around